# Icons for beta sites on accounts tab no longer show properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-accounts

In the below image, the account with '211' rep is [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com). The one with '106' rep is [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com). The icons on the badges used to match the favicon for each site until about a week ago. Now, they all display a generic beta icon. This makes them hard to distinguish without running my cursor over the badges.

I'm assuming this is a bug and not a design decision. If it was a design decision, I request that it be reversed for the sake of speed/ease of use.

Reproduced in:

- Chrome 9.0.597.98 (beta)
- Internet Explorer 9.0.7930.16406 (beta)
- Firefox 3.6.13

Reproduction links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/333652/shaun?tab=accounts
- http://answers.onstartups.com/users/flair/6837.png

[image: Beta site icons]

Comment: Oddly enough, combo flair shows the correct icons for beta sites.

Comment: Hm, this is a duplicate of something... *goes looking*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with how beta urls differ (sketchy theme) from all other sites and my local copy being out of date for testing.  It's now fixed and just got deployed to all affected sites.

*Note:* we cache generated flair images for **24 hours**, if you're looking at flair generated recently it'll take up to a day see the correct icon.

Comment: After cache expiration, this appears to be working properly. Thanks!